# mongodb $substract $dateFromString and $updateMany

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a database in mongodb with some data.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61aa1f5863d8cb985430a300"
    },
    "date": "2021-12-06T09:34:57:00.000Z",
    "name": "test",
    "nr_seq": "2",
    "latitude": "xxxxxx",
    "longitude": "xxxxxx",
    "device_id": "123456"
}
```

I have problem with field "date" this is a type string. On frontend Im trying to use on this moment.js, date-fns and nothig work, probably becouse this is a string.

Then I try to convert this data in mongodb using $toDate, $dateFromString and nothing work.

After that I use substract on this and cut off last 8 signs and save It to another collection using %out and then $dateFromString working fine.

I have done this to substract and update all:

```
db.gpsdatabase.updateMany({}, [{ $set: {date: {$substr: ["$date", 0,{$add: [{$strLenCP: "$date"}, -8]}]}}}])
```

and this to change string to date and update:

```
db.gpsdatabase.updateMany({}, [{ $set: { date: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$date", format: "%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S", onNull: "Date was empty or null", onError: "An error occurred while parsing the date string"} }}}])
```

but I think It can be done better.

How to do it easier?

I'm doing app using MERN stack.

Comment: You can use aggregation `$subtract` on date fields - in your case after converting the _string_ date value to _date_ type using the Aggregation Date Operators.

Comment: Ok. I know how to $substract $dateFromString $updateMany but can I use all off this method in one query?

Comment: You can. Look for Updates with Aggregation Pipeline feature.

Comment: MongoDB supports ISODate() format.  You could simply store the data as a date instead of a string.

Comment: I know about that. But I have a device sending date in string to database and I cant change it.